# Error in Celery: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'"

Tags: python, flask, celery

When I run the batch file to enable  Celery:

```
python.exe -m celery -A tasks worker.celery -P eventlet -f celery.logs -l info
```

An error occurs:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>               "**main**", mod_spec)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery__main__.py", line 18, in 
>       main()
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery__main__.py", line 14, in main
>               _main()
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 326, in main
>               cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 488, in execute_from_commandline
>               super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
>       
> argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 481, in setup_app_from_commandline
>       
> self.app = self.find_app(app)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 503, in find_app
>       
> return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\app\utils.py", line 355, in find_app
>       
> sym = symbol_by_name(app, imp=imp)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 506, in symbol_by_name
>       
> return imports.symbol_by_name(name, imp=imp)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\imports.py", line 56, in symbol_by_name
>       
> module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\celery\utils\imports.py", line 101, in import_from_cwd
>       
> return imp(module, package=package)
>       
> File "C:\Users\Chernov.a\Desktop\Projects\Roscosmos\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       
> return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>       
> File "", line 994, in _gcd_import
>       
> File "", line 971, in _find_and_load
>       
> File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>       
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'

I tried to add this path to the sys.path, change the virtual environment, but nothing helped.

The code itself tasks.py

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

from celery import Celery


celery_app = Celery('nsi', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')


@celery_app.task(
    name='sendToNsi',
    default_retry_delay = 4 *(60 * 60),
    max_retries =  1000,
    autoretry_for=(Exception,))

def sendToNsi(NSI_url,answer):

    s=requests.Session()
    post_request = s.post(NSI_url, data=answer,auth=HTTPBasicAuth('__', '___'))
    post_request.raise_for_status()
```

Project structure

```
───webNSI
   │   1.py
   │   config.py
   │   config1.py
   │   journal.log
   │   Message.xsd
   │   Schemas.py
   │   test2.py
   │   views - Copy.py
   │   views.py
   │   views2.py
   │   __init__.py
   │
   ├───model
   │   │   Answers.py
   │   │   DBOperation.py
   │   │   XmlHandler.py
   │   │   __init__.py
   │   │
   │   ├───MQ
   │   │   │   celery.logs
   │   │   │   CeleryMQ_Task.xml
   │   │   │   celery_worker.bat
   │   │   │   tasks.py
   │   │   │   __init__.py
   │   │   │
   │   │   └───__pycache__
   │   │           tasks.cpython-36.pyc
   │   │           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
   │   │
   │   └───__pycache__
   │           Answers.cpython-36.pyc
   │           DBOperation.cpython-36.pyc
   │           XmlHandler.cpython-36.pyc
   │           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
   │
   └───__pycache__
           config.cpython-36.pyc
           Schemas.cpython-36.pyc
           views.cpython-36.pyc
           __init__.cpython-36.pyc
           __init__.cpython-37.pyc

───__pycache__
       runserver.cpython-36.pyc
```

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please phrase your problem in english. You will reach a lot more people.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the tasks file is not visible from the path you are executing it.

try:

```
python.exe -m celery worker.celery --app=nsi -P eventlet -f celery.logs -l info
```

Comment: Thank for answer! But it doesnt't help 

    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'C'

Similar result if I try from Project source

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webnsi'

Comment: Thanks for answer! But  this result
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nsi'"

Comment: @Garciastud change nsi with yorur app_name (.py)